# return diferent values in c#

Tags: c#

What i need is a method that if the month is Januarry return a `List<cliente_ventas>` else return `List<cliente_ventas_Enero>` , The object are very similar, the difference is tht the second have more properties.

```
public class cliente_ventas 
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; } 
    .
    .
    .
    public decimal ZZZDiferencia { get; set; }
}


public class cliente_ventas_Enero
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; } 
    .
    .
    public decimal ZZZDiferencia { get; set; }
    public String Tramo { get; set; }
    public decimal EstrellasSupera { get; set; }
    public decimal EstrellasVolumen { get; set; }
}
```

What these methods do is call a stored procedure and fill out a list, so if i créate a 2 methods and call one or another(right now is what i do) does not seem practical as most of the code is common.

Comment: Hi, you need to show your own efforts, Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47905209/edit) and add all relevant code that you already wrote into it. Also please see [ask].

Comment: why not just return cliente_ventas_Enero always, but if it's January then the calling code can decide to just ignore the properties it doesn't want to use? I  think you're over-complicating the situation.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: "The object are very similar, the difference is tht the second have more properties." So can the second be derived from the first?

Comment: If these two classes are so similar is there any reason you don't have a common base class? eg `cliente_ventas_Enero` inheriting from `cliente_ventas`?

Comment: You notice that using spanish names isn't useful if you need help?

Comment: The type of the method return value will be statically compiled so you need to either make a common base class or interface that both implement, or make one of the classes inherit from the other (and thus signal that you're returning the base class type even though some of the instances will be of a derived type), or you will have to return `object`. You cannot make the type in the declaration change depending on state.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thie seccond one can inherit the other, thanks i will try to do this.

Comment: And does it really have to be a (mutable) List you return?  An IEnumerable at least allows you to use generic varience so you could have cliente_ventas_Enero:cliente_ventas and return a IEnumerable<cliente_ventas_Enero> AS a IEnumerable<cliente_ventas>

Comment: @tolanj No not have to be a List, a IEnumerable is valid, but i never use it before, there's always a first time for everything

Comment: I'd suggest instead of inheritance: 1. Use an Interface 2. Use Composition in favor of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difficulty here is: how is the caller of your method supposed to know which return value to expect?
I would suggest thinking about this carefully.

Apart from that, a possible solution would be to use cliente_ventas as a base class for cliente_ventas_Enero:

```
public class cliente_ventas 
{ 
    public string Codigo { get; set; } 
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public decimal ZZZDiferencia { get; set; }
}
public class cliente_ventas_Enero : cliente_ventas
{ 
    public String Tramo { get; set; } 
    public decimal EstrellasSupera { get; set; } 
    public decimal EstrellasVolumen { get; set; } 
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var cv in MyMethod()) 
        {
            if (cv is cliente_ventas_Enero cve)
            {
                // Do something with the variable cve (of type cliente_ventas_Enero) here.
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something with the variable cv (of type cliente_ventas) here
            }
        }
    }
    public static List<cliente_ventas> MyMethod() 
    {
        var newList = new List<cliente_ventas>();
        // depending on your logic, add instances of cliente_ventas or cliente_ventas_Enero to the list here.
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this Works, i never used before the inheritance in a real life, only view very very simple examples and never really understood the sense of using them.

Comment: Only one question, is really necessary to iterate through all the elements of the list?, if i do: if(MyMethod()[0] is cliente_ventas_Enero) {do something}  will work fine because all the elements of the List will be of the same type, no?

Comment: @Ion No problem. I showed the iteration of the list as an example only, of course you can write the code however you like, according to your requirements. Note that using the type system this way means that all the elements in the list are of type cliente_ventas or any derived type. It does not mean that all elements are the exact same type. So if the first element is type cliente_ventas_Enero, the second element does not have to be (according to the types used).

Comment: Ok now i undestood why you use the bucle, that´s not a problema in my code , in my case all of the elements will be of the same type inside the list.